# How to find all neighbors of node if the graph is not in form of adjacency matrix?

Tags: c, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I have tried to google BFS implementations in C but all of them seem to be expecting graph in form of adjacency matrix, and from what I have understood it enables  to find out all adjacent nodes in no time.

1. But what am I supposed to do to find out adjacent nodes if the input is in form of pair of nodes?
2. Am i supposed to store the edges and loop through them each time I am looking for neighbours? But that sounds slow and like something dummy like me would do :( .
3. Or am I somehow supposed to convert the input to adjacency matrix?

**Example of input**

```
{
    Nodes:
    0
    1
    2
    3
    Edges:
    0 2
    1 3
    2 3
    0 1
}
```

​

**Pseducode**

```
BFS (G, s)   //Where G is the graph and s is the source node
      let Q be queue.
      Q.enqueue( s )
      mark s as visited.
      while ( Q is not empty)
           v  =  Q.dequeue( )

          for all neighbours w of v in Graph G  /* <---------------------------------------- HOW? */
               if w is not visited 
                        Q.enqueue( w )             
                        mark w as visited.
```

from https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/breadth-first-search/tutorial/

Comment: Your "edges" part is essentially an adjacency matrix. It is giving the coordinates of the non-zero cells.

Comment: Hmm, is there a faster way to look up the adjacent node then? :/

Comment: If you have a readily available algorithm working with adj. matrix, the best for you will be just to build one, especially with such a trivial "conversion".

Comment: Well I have stumbled upon an exercise and I think that the BFS is the way to go. I tried to write it “on my own” translating that pseudocode. Didn’t know how to efficiently look up the adjacent nodes and so tried to look it up and only found code expecting adjacent matrix

Comment: BFS is working better with a different data structure (node + pointers to a adjacent nodes).

Comment: Oh, so I guess I should use different algorithm?

Comment: Algorithm is the same. Your pseudocode has no notion of the underlying data structure. But the `for all neighbours w of v` part is done more efficiently with the nodes-pointers structure.

Comment: Could you pretty please send link or try it explain it real simple? :)

Comment: The correct name is apparently "adjacency list"... https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179416/discussion-between-jack-and-eugene-sh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to google BFS implementations in C but all of them seem to be expecting graph in form of adjacency matrix, and from what I have understood it enables to find out all adjacent nodes in no time.

Well, no.  An adjacency matrix allows you to find the *set* of adjacent nodes in a nonzero amount of time that is independent of the number of nodes.  But it still takes time proportional to the number of nodes to determine what all the elements of that set are.  Other representations, such as an adjacency *list*, can allow finding the set in the same constant time, and finding its elements in time proportional to their number (which can be much less than the total number of nodes).

> 1. But what am I supposed to do to find out adjacent nodes if the input is in form of pair of nodes?

How about building an adjacency matrix or adjacency list or alternative representation, and then using it?

> 2. Am i supposed to store the edges and loop through them each time I am looking for neighbours? But that sounds slow and like something dummy like me would do :( .

A flat list of edges is one possible representation.  There are ways you could make such a list more efficient to work with (by sorting it and / or indexing it, for example), but whether that's actually a win depends on the problem.

> 3. Or am I somehow supposed to convert the input to adjacency matrix?

If indeed you want to create an adjacency matrix, then start by creating a matrix representing all the nodes, with no edges.  Read the edge list, and fill in the appropriate entry for each edge in it, or the appropriate two entries if the graph is undirected.